# How to undo changes made to a .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am fiddling around building my own CMS and playing around with the `.htaccess` file.

I was looking around the web for a snippet of code which would add a trailing slash onto every HTTP request.

When I inserted the code I realised that it would also remove the name of the subdirectory in which I was working.

**URLS:**

**So this is what I had:** localhost/project/index.php

**This is what I wanted:** localhost/projects/index.php/

**This is the result I got:** localhost/index.php/

But the real problem is this:
I saw the outcome, and I wanted to revert to example 1 from example 3. But after I deleted the code in the `.htaccess` file, the changes remained, and I have no idea how to revert this.

How do I revert this rewrite rule?

This is my `.htaccess` before implementing the "trailing slash"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /tesla0.2/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f

    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my `.htaccess` after:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /tesla0.2/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f

    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you restart apache after making changes?

Comment: I did indeed restart my MAMP server, and thereby also my apache

Comment: I found the solution. It turned out that my browser chose to cache the redirect. Which i did not think was possible. Sorry for wasting everybodies time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that youre htaccess file is in the "projects" directory?

Try changing your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

You'll also need to clear your browser's cache, since the redirect is 301 (permanent), the browser will cache the redirect and use it indefinitely, since it's a permanent redirect.